# Angular2, Karma: fail() requests NOT failing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm still programming tests for a version of the Angular.io Heroes tutorial. In writing a test for a component I run into something peculiar.  I can't make this test fail.

For example:

```
describe('OrgDetailComponent', () => {

  let comp: OrgDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrgDetailComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  let org1: Org = new Org({ ... fills Org ... });

  let dialogService: DialogService = null;
  let globalsService: GlobalsService = null;
  let orgService: OrgService = null;
  let routeStub: any = { data: Observable.of( { org: org1 } ) } ;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      providers : [
          { provide: DialogService, useClass: MockDialogService },
          { provide: GlobalsService, useClass: MockGlobalsService },
          { provide: OrgService, useClass: MockOrgService },
          { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeStub }          
      ],
      declarations: [ OrgDetailComponent ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrgDetailComponent);

    dialogService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DialogService);
    globalsService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GlobalsService);
    orgService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(OrgService);
  });

  it('should always fail', () => { 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fail('forced fail');
    });    
  });

});
```

Run this test and no failures are reported.  Wrap the fail in a try-catch.  The debugger will pause at the fail().  But you don't enter the catch().  Karma always reports success.  Whyso?

This is relevant to me because I can't prove that my tests are working.  I was writing multiple tests involving clones of these fixture.whenStable().  I had demonstratably wrong code, but as soon as I fixed only one thing that was wrong every error message went away.  Not being able to prove a failure pretty much invalidates the test suite.

Thanks for any answers,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixture.whenStable()` resolves asynchronously, so you need to use `async`

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'

it('should always fail', async(() => { 
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    fail('forced fail');
  });    
}));
```

Being wrapped in `async`, Angular will wait for all the asynchronous tasks to complete before letting the test complete. Without the `async`, the test completes before the asynchronous `whenStable()` resolves.

It's just like in your `beforeEach(async(()`. The call to `compileComponents` resolves asynchronously, so you wrap it in `async` to wait for it to complete.

Another options is to use `fakeAsync/tick` combo, which we can use to make test "seem" synchronous by forcing resolution of async tasks by calling `tick`

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing'

it('should always fail', fakeAsync(() => { 
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick()
  expect(...)    
}));
```

Assuming `fixture.detectChanges()` causes some asynchronous tasks to be performed, the `tick()` call will wait for that task to complete, so now we can treat the test as a synchronous test

**See also:**

- [Test a component with an async service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-async-service)

Comment: Do you have a tutorial website?  I'm always getting my issues answered by you!

Comment: No, no "tutorial site". I have a [blog](https://psamsotha.github.io/), but I'm not as active on it as I am on here